# Website with an up-to-date worldwide list of cell phone carriers searchable by phone number?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a website with an up-to-date worldwide list of cell phone carriers searchable by phone number?

Comment: I doubt you'll find something like that. However, here is a list with all the GSM networks around the world: http://www.gsmworld.com/roaming/gsminfo/index.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has some pretty extensive lists of mobile network operators :

- [Europe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_Europe)
- [Americas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Americas)
- [Middle East + Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Middle_East_and_Africa)
- [Asia / Pacific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators_of_the_Asia_Pacific_region)

This answers your the first part of your question - as for the second - searchable by phone number, is going to be tricky. You've not said if you just want to lookup numbers yourself or are trying to write / integrate the feature into some sort of application.

For the former, There seem to be a lot of web sites offering country specific lookups, but none/few offering global searches. The latter, integrating it into your site / app, a quick Google brings up [Mobile Network Lookup](https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-network-lookup/), this looks like a good starting point, but I'm not sure how reliable this is.

One word of warning about relying on "static" lists of data - e.g numbers 1234-0001 to 1234-4999 was assigned to Operator X. Certainly in the UK, and most of Europe, it is quite common to "port" your number to a new operator when changing contract/subscription plans. This makes such static lists obsolete quite quickly

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the Wikipedia list, but as you're pointing out it doesn't have the codes. I was looking for a website, not an API.